# How do I diagnose non-operational external USB3 hard disk drives?

Tags: usb, external-disk, mount

I have a certain combination of portable external USB 3 drives and cables that do not recognize my drive on my Mac Mini 6,2 running OSX 10.8.4. Changing the ports have not helped.

In short - All my cables work with some hard disk or the other **and** all my drives work with some cable or the other. The cable - disk combination combination that does not work on the MacMini does power up the disk and I can feel the disk spinning. The non working combinations do not even show up the drive in the `System Information` app.

I just cannot figure out how to figure out what is wrong. A cable - disk combination that refuses to work on the MacMini works just fine my Windows 8 Dell Notebook. Is there any way to diagnose the problem? How?

Comment: And does this disk show up in Disk Utilities? I have to say, I've had this happen from one different MBPro to the next; some portables like a USB to mini USB ... have no answers yet except treasure the combo of disk and cable that works.

Comment: No. It does not show up in the disk utilities either :-(